# Codeigniter: combining anchor, base URL and a database variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, base-url

```
 <?php echo anchor('gamma/viewGamma/' . $gamma->GammaID, '<img src="' . base_url() . APPPATH . 'images/covers/' . $gamma->Naam .  'width="10%" float="left" class="hvr-pop">'); ?>
```

I need an overview of icons to select from to show a company's products.
The link itself works but the image does not get shown.
The html output is the following: http://web.website.local/application/images/covers/imagenamewidth="

Also, the code comes from database (Varchar) and should say imagename.jpg instead of imagename

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: $gamma is an instance of an object. The imagename is stored in the property Naam. So only if we now the logic of you object we can tell how to fix this issue.

Comment: The object contains imagename+extension in varchar (imagename.jpg)
$gamma is a get function from the database where Naam is the name of the product. But that's not the issue here since the value that comes from $gamma works perfectly. I just need to close my  "img src" behind the $gamma->GammaID part. But I don't know how.

the output from the code is the following:
<img class="hvr-pop" float="left" 10%"="" src="http://web.site.local/images/covers/imagenamewidth=">
I need to be able ot close src after imagename wich just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `APP_PATH` as it is physical path.

And image `src` needs `url`.

Corrected Code:

```
<?php echo anchor('gamma/viewGamma/' . $gamma->GammaID, '<img src="' . base_url() . 'images/covers/' . $gamma->Naam .  'width="10%" float="left" class="hvr-pop">'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when testing this code i still have the closing tag problem;
<img class="hvr-pop" float="left" 10%"="" src="http://web.site.local/images/covers/VB-Awidth="> is the output i get (where VB-A should have a closing " tag and a spacing before width